# SO_MARK valid values

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking

What are valid and meaningful values for [`SO_MARK`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html)? I found some projects use `int`, some `unsigned int` ([dnsmasq](https://thekelleys.org.uk/gitweb/?p=dnsmasq.git;a=blob;f=src/forward.c;h=04635b375a9b8da2bc6ed231369c8a44d964e876;hb=HEAD#l118)):

```
unsigned int mark;
if (get_incoming_mark(&forward->frec_src.source, &forward->frec_src.dest, 0, &mark))
     setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_MARK, &mark, sizeof(unsigned int));
```

I suppose using `unsigned int` is correct (thus this PR for `ping` is probably correct: https://github.com/iputils/iputils/pull/345). But `ping` allows user to specify `SO_MARK`, thus I'd like to also add check for valid input.

Also, can I see `SO_MARK` setup in wireshark/tcpdump output?

Comment: I would say it's better to explicitly define it as 32-bit unsigned integer, e.g. `uint32_t`. In most related linux headers, e.g. of netfilter, you will find it defined as `__u32` type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `struct sock` structure used by the kernel for sockets [defines the field](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/include/net/sock.h#L448) set by `SO_MARK` as: `__u32 sk_mark`. So I'd say any `uint32_t` is a meaningful value for this option.

> Also, can I see `SO_MARK` setup in wireshark/tcpdump output?

AFAIK no, the `mark` is not actually set on the packets (at any layer), it's just set on internal kernel structures used to manage the socket (`struct sock`) and packet control information (`struct sk_buff`). You will not see it "on the wire".

You could however use `iptables` to log marked packets to dmesg, like [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/507020/272806) on Unix & Linux SE suggests:

```
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -m mark ! --mark 0 -m limit --limit 8/min --limit-burst 12 -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTables-Marks: "

$ ./send-some-marked-packets ...

$ sudo dmesg
...
[27448.839237] IPTables-Marks: IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=31 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=45988 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=40656 DPT=12345 LEN=11 MARK=0xcc
```

Comment: Agree with `uint32_t` but [`ping`](https://github.com/iputils/iputils/tree/master/ping) from iputils uses everywhere non-fixed sizes (i.e. `int` or `unsigned int`) - it needs cleanup. Or just maybe before this cleanup just accept `unsigned int` because it's 4 bytes on both 32bit and 64 bit? It also check for value in range `<0, INT_MAX>`, [PR](https://github.com/iputils/iputils/pull/345/files) suggest to change to `<0, UINT_MAX>` anyway. NOTE: feel free to reply to the PR.

Comment: @pevik yeah that is definitely not the cleanest way to do it. Depending on the platform/architecture they target, `int` could very well still be a valid option. For example, on x86 + GCC an `int` is 32 bit and can assume exactly all the values that `unsigned int` can (in terms of bit patterns). In such case, if the data type is `int`, checking for validity with `>= 0 && <= INT_MAX` is not that good of an idea as it would only exclude half of the possible (still valid) values. Checking that an `unsigned int` is in the range `[0, UINT_MAX]` is just useless, it's always true.

Comment: @pevik I would also argue that the manual page for [`man 7 socket`](https://manned.org/socket.7) should be updated, as it currently says *"Unless otherwise noted, `optval` is a pointer to an `int`"*, but does not indicate any different type for `SO_MARK`.

Comment: I would say it should still be `uint32_t` and the argument parser should check for a value between `0` an `UINT32_MAX`. @MarcoBonelli that argument parser probably uses `strtol` so it should actually check for the range.

Comment: @Cheatah oh yeah, if `strtol` is used then the check is needed. I mostly agree with you, but I don't know how the authors of `ping` maintain their program, they may have guarantees that `int` is 4 bytes and just go with it.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Do I understand you properly, that id does not mean if I keep type `int` or change to `unsigned int`, what matters is the check validity for `>=0 && <= UINT32_MAX`? Maybe the clearest way would be to add `uint32_t` and check for `>=0 && <= 4294967295 (i.e. value of  `UINT32_MAX` max `unsigned int` on 64 bit.

Comment: Also, the construct in the code `rts.mark = strtol_or_err(optarg, _("invalid argument"), 0, UINT_MAX)` the function `strtol_or_err()` does check also whether parameter passed to user is integer. For variant `unsigned int` type sure we could add function without `min` and `max` check.